# InArgument not showing up in crm 2011 Workflow web designer

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom activity with an InArgument like so:

```
public sealed class MyCodeActivity : CodeActivity{
[Input("Some name")]
[ReferenceEntity("contact")]
[Required]
public InArgument<EntityReference> InputContact{get;set;}

   public override Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
   {
     //do something
   } 
 }
```

After registering this activity using the plugin registration tool, I created a new workflow and added this activity to the web workflow designer. But when i click "Set Properties" the InArgument does not show up.Am I missing something?

Comment: I have had in arguments "Magically appear" after resetting my server.  An inargument<EntityReference> must have the input and referenceentity attributes, or it doesn't show up in the designer's "set properties" dialog.  If this is the case, try doing a reset of the worker processes associated with workflows.

Comment: @fauxtrot: Interesting. Which process is the worker process for workflows?

Comment: Try IIS (as mentioned below) and crmasyncservice and crmsandboxservice (I don't remember if that is the exact spelling of each of the latter two processes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have registered workflow activity you need to restart the microsoft CRM dynamics in the IIS and Microsoft CRM asynchronous process service, then if you add it to the workflow changes will be there.

Comment: +1 I recently started working with workflows and this was a great tip for inputs that were not showing up through the CRM interface even though they were declared in my workflow class. An IIS reset did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question is already answered I wanted to share two cases where the provided solution didn't work:

### Case 1

Having choosen Input-Parameter names that contained german umlauts (äöüß).

IIS-restart did not help.
Choosing names without umlauts solved the problem for me.

### Case 2

We recently also had a case where a normal In-Argument did not show up, even after restarting the entire machine CRM was running on. The Solution was not to obvious:

1. Open PluginRegistrationTool from SDK
2. Choose the Assembly that contains your CWA
3. Choose your CWA
4. Hit the Save-Button in the Properties tab of your CWA

Comment: I followed the steps in Case 2 and it worked. No IIS reset or async process restart required